# Why is there a need to disable enter keypress to submit form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web

Some sites that has long forms are understandable.

It bothers me that some site that only have a simple login input, e.g. https://www.maybank2u.com.my disable the enter key when you only have ONE field. It's so counter-intuitive and frustrate the user. They even explicitly state that you have to press the button. Is there a specific needs for this? I don't see any, even from security perspective.

The fact that it's a banking site doesn't even matter. Other banks just works fine. Is this just a poor workmanship or there is a legit reason behind the decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in their case they made the decision to disable it, because from just a few tests it seems that the username lookup is a very expensive process (try typing in a random username like `BarryWhite` and see how long it takes for the server to respond and what message you see); some people might type their username incorrectly and hit enter without realising their mistake thus wasting processing time.

Generally, there would be no need to do this because as you said it is counter intuitive. However in this case it makes sense from their perspective until they fix the underlying issue (if at all).